# Inverse cubic function

Tags: inverse-function, cubics

I'm looking for a way to find the inverse of a function that resembles something like this, ${f(x)=x^{3}+4x+2}$. So one of the “form” $f(x)=x^{3}+ax+b$.

I am told that it has an inverse function, $ $   $ f^{-1}(x)$ , and that $f(0)=2$.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You were told that $f(0)=2$? The expression for $f$ is $f(x)=x^3+4x+2$ and you need that someone tells you that $f(0)=2$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos :) I have no idea. I was asked to help with this question by a friend of mine who's doing undergrad calculus.. The question also formulated the funny statement: "$f(0)=2$ ..

Comment: @Kristian Then I strongly suspect that the problem that your friend was supposed to solve was to compute $(f^{-1})'(2)$. Am I right?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yeah you are. Is it easier to evaluate at a single point? 
I know that $f(f^{-1}(x))$ should give $x$ itself, right?

Comment: @Kristian I posted an answer to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, as you told me in the comments, consists in computing $(f^{-1})'(2)$. Since $f(0)=2$, $f^{-1}(2)=0$, and therefore$$(f^{-1})'(2)=\frac1{f'\bigl(f^{-1}(2)\bigr)}=\frac1{f'(0)}=\frac14.$$You don't have to determine $f^{-1}(x)$ for every $x$ in order to do this.